# MySQL config file units discrepancy

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a 2GB RAM machine running MySQL.

When I set my innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf to "1G", the MySQL process uses around 1.3GB which is the expected behaviour. However, when I set it to "1000M" the RAM runs out and the MySQL process crashes.

According to the documentation "M" stands for Megabytes and "G" for Gigabytes. So, 1000M should be the same as 1G. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: `1G` equals `1024M`. [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) say "Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances" but also suggest it will fix invalid values automatically.

Comment: That multiply requirement is probably it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For only 2GB of RAM, neither 1000M nor 1G is a reasonable value for that setting.  When MySQL swaps, it gets a lot slower.  So, it is better to avoid swapping than to have a high value for the buffer_pool.  Recommend only 500M.

Comment: According to system metrics, MySQL hasn't swapped once. The server only runs the database so there is really no sense in keeping 75% of RAM empty for nothing. I could even use more than 1GB according to https://scalegrid.io/blog/calculating-innodb-buffer-pool-size-for-your-mysql-server/.

Comment: How much RAM is the OS taking?  How much is the _rest_ of MySQL taking?  I doubt if you can safely set it any bigger than 500M.  You have already found out that some version of 1G is too big.

Comment: @MaxF - and, in that link:  Approach 1 only works if you have a lot of RAM.  80% of even a mere 4G is unsafe.  Approach is what my previous Comment is alluding to.

Comment: @MaxF - Furthermore, their Approach 2 says "256MB + 256 * log2(RAM size in GB)", which equals 512M; essentially what I recommended.

Comment: Yeah I went with approach 2 and no, the formula is to calculate the system overhead, not the RAM to use, so you'd take 2GB-result of formula. You are right that MySQL will use more than buffer pool size but 1G as value should be fine. I am running with 1G right now, MySQL RAM use is 1.3 GiB and the free RAM never drops under 350M. 1000M as a value is probably not working because of the reason that Alvaro mentioned above.